# How to create multiple consumers for kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

I am working on adding multiple consumers in kafka. Right now there's is only one consumer but if I want more consumers, is there a way where i can add them through bash file. The kafka consumer in this case is declared in a java file and is declared by setting properties. I am not sure how to use properties through shell in this case. Thanks in advance

I have tried adding consumer in java file but i need to add them via bash

Answer (score 0):

> through bash

Use `&` to send process to the background

E.g. To create 2 consumers in the same consumer group

```bash
kafka-console-consumer --topic foo --group bar ... &
kafka-console-consumer --topic foo --group bar ... &
```

> The kafka consumer in this case is declared in a java file

Then run the Java process multiple times

```bash
java jar app.jar &
java jar app.jar &
```

Or, use threads. https://github.com/confluentinc/parallel-consumer

> not sure how to use properties through shell

You would use `String[] args` to extract a file name in your Java code. Then you pass that as an argument to your code.

```bash
java jar app.jar app.properties &
java jar app.jar app.properties &
```